# shell script rsync password file option

Tags: linux, shell, backup, rsync

In a shell script how to use `rsync --password-file` option

```
rsync -a root@123.123.12.3:/root /backup
```

Answer (score 3):

If protocol is rsync you can use:

```
rsync -a --password-file=/path/to/secret rsync://root@123.123.12.3/root /backup
```

If rsync over ssh used, you should setup public key ssh auth. On local host run

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024
```

then add content of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on remote host.

Comment: Did u try this rsync -a --password-file=/path/to/secret rsync://root@123.123.12.3/root /backup
I tried this before and from the man pages and it didnt work